# vba - finding the xpath of a node

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xpath

c.Value is a text from a cell (typical values are: name, type, weight, currency but could be anything) in the first row of the sheet.

filenames is a loop from Dir() basically looping thru XMLs in a folder.

These xmls may have  the lowest level node 'weight' (for example) but under multiple different parent nodes. Ie these 3 different xpaths: //Client/personal/weight and //Client/details/weight and //Client/details/info/weight.

I've got this code:

```
   Dim aDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim aNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Set aDoc = LoadXmlDoc(filenames(f))
    Set aNodes = aDoc.getElementsByTagName(c.Value)
For f = 1 To UBound(filenames)
    If aNodes.Length > 0 Then 'if at least one node is present
       For Each aNode In aNodes 'loop thru each occurence of a node
          c.Offset(f, 0).Value = aNode.Text & "parent is " & aNode.parentNode.parentNode
       Next
    End If
Nxt f
```

What I'm trying to do is get a distinct list of the xpaths for the child node I specify in c.value.

For example,

```
if c.value is weight
```

I'm trying to get this list back:

```
//Client/personal/weight
//Client/details/weight
//Client/details/info/weight.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163921(office.10).aspx is a good reference but I can't seem to find how to get the xpath from a child node. I just managed to get the immediate parent node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with the node and walk up its parents until you reach the document level.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim oNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim pNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim XML As String, sPath As String

    XML = "<Client><LastName>Bill</LastName><FirstName>Gates</FirstName>" & _
    "<MiddleName/><Suffix/><DateOfBirth>30-May-1968</DateOfBirth>" & _
    "<PlaceOfBirth/><SSN>n/a</SSN><Gender>Male</Gender><District>" & _
    "<City>SHELTON</City><Mayor>wong</Mayor></District><State>WA</State>" & _
    "<Zip>96484</Zip></Client>"

    oDoc.LoadXML XML

    Set oNodes = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("City")
    If oNodes.Length > 0 Then

        For Each oNode In oNodes
            sPath = oNode.nodeName
            Set pNode = Nothing
            Do
                If pNode Is Nothing Then
                    Set pNode = oNode.ParentNode
                Else
                    Set pNode = pNode.ParentNode
                End If

                If pNode.nodeTypeString <> "document" Then
                    sPath = pNode.nodeName & "/" & sPath
                Else
                    sPath = "//" & sPath
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            Debug.Print sPath
        Next oNode
    End If

End Sub
```